# SQL Server Management Studio fatal error during installation 0x80070643

Tags: ssms

I am trying to install SSM 18.8 release. I get at then end of the installation process a fatal error 0x80070643. There's also another detail shown and I presume that is causing the error.
"Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client : There's a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this installation to complete could not be run. "

The same error detail was shown while installing the 16.5.3 release as well as when installing Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client.

Comment: Uninstall the SQL Server 2012 Native Client first then rerun the installer.

Comment: Well, The SQL Server 2012 Native Client didn't install. What I did was to repair my C++ Run-times and the installation resumed successfully !